# Does constructing an RSA crypto service provider persist or leak key data?

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I read in another article here that code such as this would result in .NET persisting the key into a random key store (presumably in the registry) from the machine that it was created. Is this true and under what conditions would it persist vs not persist? Would persistence still happen if key was initialized from a string?

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider alg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
```

It appears to be true?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2010/01/29/while-creating-cryptographic-keys-or-key-containers-repeatedly-your-hard-disk-may-get-filled-with-lots-of-files-and-may-end-up-filling-the-whole-hard-disk-space-if-not-deleted.aspx

---- Now I'm not sure.. when I debug on my machine PersistInCspContainer is set to false.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the confusion is in this part of the spec:

> The `PersistKeyInCsp` property is automatically set to true when you
>   specify a key container name in a `CspParameters` object and use it to
>   initialize an RSACryptoServiceProvider object. You can specify a
>   container name using the `KeyContainerName` field. If you set the
>   `PersistKeyInCsp` property to true without initializing the
>   `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object with a `CspParameters` object, a random
>   key container name prepended with `"CLR"` is created.

It seems to me that you have to provide either the `CspParameters` or set `PersistKeyInCsp` to true to persist keys. At least, that's how I read it and your experiment seems to match.

It's probably like PKCS#11 tokens; keys are session objects by default.